Python "decimal" module for numerical computation: how do I use it?
so I'm trying to modify the precision used in my code. the only method (I know of) is using the "decimal" module. but I'm not really sure how to use it. I'm not entirely new to Python, but I'm still learning how to implement some of the fundamentals, so modules like this one are kind of new to me  and I'd really appreciate your help :(
for examle, in my code, I have the following definition
def f(R):
    z = R - ((c1 * (mHS ** 2) * (( ((R) / (mHS**2) )) ** nHS))) / (1 + c2 * (((R) / (mHS ** 2)) ** nHS))
    return z

where all variables (except "R") have been previously defined as constants. if I were to use the "decimal" module, aside from writing "from decimal import *" and then "getcontext().prec = 6" at the top of my code:

where (in the function I defined) should I put the "Decimal()" class? should I apply it to every single variable and number? should I apply it only to the whole thing my function returns (i.e. "Decimal(z)")? should I just apply it to the numbers (there I only have "1" and "2")? should I apply it to the argument I define in my function? probably not the last one, but I hope you get a feeling for what I'm trying to say with these questions.

the code I'm writing is a fourth order Runge-Kutta method. so I also use these functions (defined by me) to add and multiply other things. that is, I also operate with these functions and I need to maintain a set precision throughout the whole algorithm. what do I do then? I saw something about using "quantize()" but "Decimal()" already confuses me enough to not use "quantize()" yet.

aside from the last point, I want to avoid the whole "0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004" situation in python (which I kind of understand that "Decimal" takes care of that?). and I wouldn't like to carry extra decimals after operations are computed (e.g. always get a number with 64 "decimals" and truncate everything else after operating it. maybe 64 is a lot, but imagine a precision higher than the default double precision in python with truncated decimal values -I'm aware that higher precision will slow down the time it takes to compile/run my code). and again, I kind of understand that "Decimal" takes care of that? I just don't know how to use it correctly.


I know some of these (if not all) might sound like dumb questions, but I'd really appreciate your help.
I have checked the documentation; but I'm not really sure how to specifically apply it to my problem.

On point 3, Decimal does not eliminate rounding error. It makes rounding error line up a bit better with human intuition, since typical human intuition is based on decimal, but you'll still get rounding error. For something like a fourth-order Runge-Kutta method, Decimal is unlikely to make the results any more intuitive.

Note that Decimal is far from the only option for precision beyond float and may in fact be undesirable. Decimal exists for, well, decimal math, i.e. base 10 as opposed to float's base 2. This still carries some problems of fixed-base math with it, e.g. 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 won't work robustly. In the standard library there's also fractions for rational number math. There are some third-party libraries like mpmath for more performant arbitrary precision math as well.

It might help to fill in the details on the example: what are the constants, what's an example input to the function, what output are you getting now, and what would a more precise output look like.

Before you use Decimal for this check first that float (which in Python is actually 64bit double) isn't already adequate for your problem. I doubt if RK4 will need much more than that unless your functions are incredibly close to singular. There are well tested library implementations of most classic DE solvers. numpy.longdouble might give you a bit more headroom at 80bit on Intel x64. Or RK4
as scipy.integrate

@MartinBrown : RK45 is the Dormand-Prince 5th order method with variable step size driven by the difference to the embedded 4th order method. It is not in any way based on W. M. Kutta's "classical" 4th order Heun and Simpson inspired fixed-step RK4 method.
